# Servlet package is not available while building of servlet api and throwing compile time error servlet package is not available

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0

i want to try to create a maven project for Servlet api. I have a created a servlet with name HelloWorldServlet as follow:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWord")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorldServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("do post method called");
    }

}
```

At the time of building the project it is throwing following error:

```
ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Project_Work/Other_learn/eclipse_workspace_lear/servletapi/src/main/java/com/learn/servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java:[6,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Project_Work/Other_learn/eclipse_workspace_lear/servletapi/src/main/java/com/learn/servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java:[7,32] package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Project_Work/Other_learn/eclipse_workspace_lear/servletapi/src/main/java/com/learn/servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Project_Work/Other_learn/eclipse_workspace_lear/servletapi/src/main/java/com/learn/servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java:[9,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Project_Work/Other_learn/eclipse_workspace_lear/servletapi/src/main/java/com/learn/servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java:[10,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Project_Work/Other_learn/eclipse_workspace_lear/servletapi/src/main/java/com/learn/servlet/HelloWorldServlet.java:[16,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class HttpServlet
```

I have added the below jar files in the build path:
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar and servlet-api.jar

So i request you guys to let me know what i am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding a library to Eclipse's build path does not automatically add it the maven build generated file. that file will be added only if it is loaded through adding it's dependency in the pom file.

So here we need to follow two steps, first we copy the jar file to the maven local repository and then add it's dependency to the pom.xml file as follow:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>servlet-api-id</id>
    <phase>clean</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>install-file</goal>                // copy file to local maven repo
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <file>${project.basedir}/lib/servlet-api.jar</file>
    </configuration>
  </execution> 
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

-> and then add dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```